# SPARQL query on the remote remote endpoint RDFLib / Redland

Tags: python, rdf, sparql, rdflib, redland

I'm trying to query remote endpoints and get get owl:sameAs mappings, I've tried both RDFLib and Redland but neither worked for me, probably I'm not dealing with namespaces correctly.

Here is my attempt in RDFLib:

```
    import rdflib

    rdflib.plugin.register('sparql', rdflib.query.Processor, 'rdfextras.sparql.processor', 'Processor')
    rdflib.plugin.register('sparql', rdflib.query.Result, 'rdfextras.sparql.query', 'SPARQLQueryResult')

    g = rdflib.Graph()

    query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM <http://api.talis.com/stores/bbc-backstage/services/sparql>
        WHERE {
             ?s a http://purl.org/ontology/mo/MusicArtist;
                http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs ?o .
        }Limit 50
    """

    for row in g.query(query):
        print row
```

And here is Redland:

```
import RDF
model = RDF.Model()

query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM <http://api.talis.com/stores/bbc-backstage/services/sparql>
    WHERE {
         ?s a http://purl.org/ontology/mo/MusicArtist;
            http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs ?o .
    }Limit 50
"""

for statement in RDF.Query(query ,query_language="sparql").execute(model):
    print statement
```

Can you please give a hint what is wrong in any one of those?
Yet another difficulty I have: Is it possible to get dataset name of the object? For example: if there is:

```
?s = http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/artists/eb5c8564-927d-414d-b152-c7b48a2c9d8b#artist
predicate = http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs
?0 = http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Boy_Least_Likely_To
```

Can I get name of the "Dbpedia" in this example? Or any other dataset to which I'm having sameAs link? (Or probably I could just look-up interested dataset names in the object string) thank you very VERY much in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Various things:

You are right, you need to enclose any URI within `<` `>`. The correct query is:

```
SELECT ?s ?o WHERE {
         ?s a <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/MusicArtist>;
            <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?o .
    } limit 50
```

... see the results [here](http://api.talis.com/stores/bbc-backstage/services/sparql?query=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?s%20a%20%3Chttp://purl.org/ontology/mo/MusicArtist%3E;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs%3E%20?o%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20limit%2050).

`FROM` is not implemented in rdflib or redland as you think it is. It does not fetch remote SPARQL endpoints it fetches remote graphs or graphs with that name in a local store. In your case you want to use `SERVICE` see [how it works here with Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/service.html). Unfortunately, neither rdflib nor redland implement the `SERVICE` clause for SPARQL but there are workarounds to sort this out.

One possible solution is to use [SPARQLWrapper for python](http://sparql-wrapper.sourceforge.net/). It is trivial, here you have your code with that library:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://api.talis.com/stores/bbc-backstage/services/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    SELECT ?s ?o
    WHERE {
         ?s a <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/MusicArtist>;
            <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?o .
    } limit 50
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print result["s"]['value'], result["o"]['value']
```

As you can see the remote SPARQL endpoint becomes a parameter outside the query.

Answer (score 3):

Redland does not currently support using SPARQL endpoints in FROM.  What you are using here are are *graph names* that you load into the RDF Dataset. Also known as redland contexts when you load a triple (s, p, o) + c with something like `model.context_add_statement(statement, context)`

Rasqal GIT does support parsing `SERVICE` but not yet executing it in a query.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider using [Virtuoso with RedLand](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFDriverRedland) as it implement the SPARQL-FED "Service" param for remote query execution as demonstrated in these [online examples](http://www.delicious.com/kidehen/sparql_fed_demo)

Answer (score 2):

There's another simple solution in the blog entry at http://terse-words.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-real-data-from-semantic-web.html which keeps the code fairly clean. It uses SPARQLWrapper as well.